# How to create shape image border with clickable container?(use HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, border, css

I want create the border show in the picture but i want to stay clickable the under picture of frame.

I use a div on the other div,it's work but under div is not clickable.
I use border image,but the corner of left bottom is not create like the picture.
Any other way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8HSs.jpg

I am using .png picture that cut center of that png picture. 
My code is this:

```html
<div id="slideshow204" class="slideshow" style="position:absolute;top:22px;right: 34px;z-index: 1;">
  ......
  </div>
<div class="decor"><img style="position: absolute;z-index: 4;" src="http://shakeri.info/images/logo/zendeginameh.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: For the div not clickable are you using z-index in css with a negative number value?

Comment: You can see my demo work bottom of this page: <br><b>http://shakeri.info/<b>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
I must add

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

to the png's div to clickable under div.
need detail?
[Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)